# How to transfer parameter as an attribute to request xml in soapui

Tags: soapui

I need to pass a unique value generated as parameter to request xml.

Created a parameter name = name${=(int)(Math.random()*100)}

Request xml:

```
<toy>
<name>${name}</name>
</toy>
```

it accepts ${name} in the above request.
But if passed as an attribute

```
 <toy name="${name}"/>
```

${name} is not recognized here. Can somebody please help how to pass parameter value to attribute in an xml.

Comment: What is: "Created a parameter name = name${=(int)(Math.random()*100)}"? Where did you create it? What syntax is that? Please explain and correct. As it stands, it is nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

I am surprised it works for you in the first case.

As per [documentation](http://www.soapui.org/scripting---properties/property-expansion.html#1-Property-Expansion-in-soapUI), to use property expansion you should specify the scope of the property: `${#TestCase#name}`.

Comment: That doesnot work as well not sure if it is because the attribute is inside xml tag as the value is null even if its with/without quotes

Answer (score 0):

As @siKing said the scope it's necessary for property expansion, however there is one case where you can use the property name without scope as you do with `${name}`; for example if you've a testCase and within it you've a groovy testStep where you put a variable in a context using `context.setProperty('name','value')` , then for the rest of testSteps in this testCase you can use `${name}`. I suppose that this is your case.

Anyway if you've correctly set the property you can use `${name}` in node text or in attribute, for me it works for both cases (at least with SOAPUI 5.0.0 version). Furthermore If I use directly your groovy code inside a soap testStep `${=(int)(Math.random()*100)}` in a node or in attribute also work for both cases. You can check the `raw` view to make it sure if it really works:

[image]

Hope it helps,